# Autocompletion of reactJS javascript elements in sublime text 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I've spent some time configuring a Sublime Text 3 to have a proper ReactJS IDE. Babel does the highlighting, Emmet the HTML-within-JSX code completion suggestions and ternJS does the Javascript code completion. I'm missing however a code completion plugin for the Javascript parts of React (E.g. autocompletion after writing the point in `this.` within a component function, autocomplete for the component functions, when accessing a top level element from ReactDOM or React classes after writing a point like in `ReactDOM.` or `React.` etc

My bet is to use a ternJS plugin to have React autocomplete library as the ones you can get after modding your .tern-project like in

```
{
  "libs": [
    "browser",
    "ecmascript",
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "chai"
  ],
  "plugins": {
    "requirejs": {},
    "modules": {},
    "es_modules": {},
    "commonjs": {},
    "complete_strings": {},
    "node_resolve": {},
    "node": {}
  }
}
```

Is there any appropiated library for ternJS? Am I missing a feature from previously mentioned plugins? Should I use a different one?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No. And with React Native around maybe it will remain frozen